# Embed image uploaded by form to google doc using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have been trying to find the answer to this for a while...

I have a google form (for this example I am going to say it is a check list for a vehicle). So I fill in the form, answers go to a sheet and app script within the sheet makes a copy of a doc template, replaces keywords and then saves and emails a pdf. This works absolutely fine.

I am trying to add in image upload by form as a few of the answers. The image uploads to drive fine but i dont know what to put in the app script to make the image embed into the doc so that the image is present on the pdf that is emailed. right now it just provides a drive link to the image. I hope i made sense.

```
// Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = "doc ID"; 
var docName = "Vehicle check with images";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
var email_address = "myemailaddress@here.com";
var vehicle_vrn = e.values[1];
var front_desc = e.values[2];
var front_image = e.values[3];
var rear_desc = e.values[4];
var rear_image = e.values[5];
var driver_desc = e.values[6];
var driver_image = e.values[7];
var passenger_desc = e.values[8];
var passenger_image = e.values[9];



// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+vehicle_vrn)
.getId();
// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keyVrn', vehicle_vrn);
copyBody.replaceText('keyFrontdesc', front_desc);
copyBody.replaceText('keyFrontimage', front_image);
copyBody.replaceText('keyReardesc', rear_desc);
copyBody.replaceText('keyRearimage', rear_image);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDriversdesc', driver_desc);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDriversimage', driver_image);
copyBody.replaceText('keyPassdesc', passenger_desc);
copyBody.replaceText('keyPassimage', passenger_image);


// Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Attach PDF and send the email
var subject = "V Check with images concept";
var body = "Please find attached the completed vehicle check with images for " + vehicle_vrn + "";
MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete temp file
DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand about your situation as follows.

- When a file is uploaded using Google Form, the file is uploaded to Google Drive, the URL of the file like `https://drive.google.com/open?id=### fileId ###` can be retrieved as the event object.

  - In this script, such URL is used for retrieving the blob from the file.
- It supposes that from your question and your script, the place and number of images you want to replace are as follows.

  - There are `keyVrn`, `keyFrontdesc`, `keyFrontimage`, `keyReardesc`, `keyRearimage`, `keyDriversdesc`, `keyDriversimage`, `keyPassdesc` and `keyPassimage` in the document. And each value is only one.
  - `front_image`, `rear_image`, `driver_image` and `passenger_image` are the uploaded files. You want to replace from `keyFrontimage`, `keyRearimage`, `keyDriversimage` and `keyPassimage` to them.
- You want to send the document including the replaced text and images as a PDF file.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- Although the text value can be replaced using `replaceText()`, the text cannot be replaced to an image using it. So I used the following flow for this.

  1. Find the text value you want to replace using findText().
  2. Delete the text using setText().
  3. Insert an image to the deleted text using insertInlineImage().

The script which reflected above points is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
// Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = "doc ID"; 
var docName = "Vehicle check with images";

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, fileId) {
    var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
    var r = body.findText(searchText).getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, blob);
  }

  //Get information from form and set as variables
  var email_address = "myemailaddress@here.com";
  var vehicle_vrn = e.values[1];
  var front_desc = e.values[2];
  var front_image = e.values[3].split("=")[1];
  var rear_desc = e.values[4];
  var rear_image = e.values[5].split("=")[1];
  var driver_desc = e.values[6];
  var driver_image = e.values[7].split("=")[1];
  var passenger_desc = e.values[8];
  var passenger_image = e.values[9].split("=")[1];

  // Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
  .makeCopy(docName+' for '+vehicle_vrn)
  .getId();
  // Open the temporary document
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  // Get the document’s body section
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getBody();

  copyBody.replaceText('keyVrn', vehicle_vrn);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyFrontdesc', front_desc);
  replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'keyFrontimage', front_image);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyReardesc', rear_desc);
  replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'keyRearimage', rear_image);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDriversdesc', driver_desc);
  replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'keyDriversimage', driver_image);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPassdesc', passenger_desc);
  replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'keyPassimage', passenger_image);

  copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
  var subject = "sample attachment file";
  var body = "sample text: " + vehicle_vrn + "";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
  DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

#### References :

- [replaceText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replaceText(String,String))
- [findText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern)
- [setText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#settexttext)
- [insertInlineImage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#insertinlineimagechildindex-image)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit :

When you want to resize the inserted image, please modify as follows. In this modification, the image is converted to 300 pixel. Please modify this for your situation.

#### From :

```
  var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, fileId) {
    var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
    var r = body.findText(searchText).getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, blob);
  }
```

#### To :

```
  var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, fileId) {
    var width = 300; // Please set this.
    var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
    var r = body.findText(searchText).getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, blob);
    var w = img.getWidth();
    var h = img.getHeight();
    img.setWidth(width);
    img.setHeight(width * h / w);
  }
```

Comment: Your modification worked exactly as I needed. All I need to do is set an image size for the images to be roughly half the width of an A4.   I thank you for your time.

Comment: @Steve Haddley I'm really sorry for my incomplete answer. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I was searching for tips on how to resize image. Was about to make a start but came back to this page first and again I owe you a thank you. It is perfect as to what I wanted

Comment: @Steve Haddley Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: @ Tanaike It has been a little over a year and the code is still going strong and has been edited for a few different uses. I am hoping you are still active and still willing to help.

I now need to also save the pdf to a specified folder
I also need to add a link to the pdf in a column within the sheet

is this possible?

Comment: @Steve Haddley I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Steve Haddley Thank you for your response. It's no problem. When I saw your new question, I would like to confirm it and think of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post, I finally managed to get the images into my PDF using the code from [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) where I was having to include them in the email body (which I still use at the moment too)

Here is my code as it is a bit different from yours but should still work the same.

```
  function onFormSubmit1(e) {
   
 
  //open the template document by ID
  //you can find the ID in the link of the document
  var templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('GDOC TEMPLATE FILE ID HERE');
  //create a copy of the template, we don't wanna mess up the template doc
  var newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy();
  
  //open the new template document for editing
  var openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  var body = openDoc.getBody();

  // image

  var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, fileId) {
    var width = 500; // Please set this.
    var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
    var r = body.findText(searchText).getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, blob);
    var w = img.getWidth();
    var h = img.getHeight();
    img.setWidth(width);
    img.setHeight(width * h / w);
  }
  
  //get the responses triggered by On Form Submit
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  
  //find the text in the template doc and replace it with the Form response
  //items[0].getResponse() is the first response in the Form
  //and it is the "Name"
  body.replaceText('{Rack}', items[0].getResponse());  
  body.replaceText('{door}', items[14].getResponse());
  body.replaceText('{list}', items[1].getResponse());
  body.replaceText('{entry}', items[2].getResponse());
  body.replaceText('{no}', items[3].getResponse());
  body.replaceText('{held}', items[4].getResponse());
  body.replaceText('{open}', items[5].getResponse());
  body.replaceText('{bgu}', items[6].getResponse());
  body.replaceText('{forced}', items[7].getResponse());
  body.replaceText('{pin}', items[8].getResponse());
  body.replaceText('{fail}', items[9].getResponse());
  //body.replaceText('{pic}', items[10].getResponse());
  body.replaceText('{any}', items[13].getResponse());
  var image1 = items[10].getResponse();
  var image2 = items[11].getResponse();
  var image3 = items[12].getResponse();
  
  replaceTextToImage(body, 'image1', image1);
  replaceTextToImage(body, 'image2', image2);
  replaceTextToImage(body, 'image3', image3);

  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  //You can add as much as you have and change them in the Template Doc like this
  //body.replaceText('{number}', items[2].getResponse());
  //body.replaceText('{choice}', items[3].getResponse());
  //and so on...
  //function insertImage () {
 
      openDoc.saveAndClose();
      var theBlob = newTempFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
      //The name of the file is going to be the first and second question from the form
      //change to your preference

      var d = new Date();
      var curr_date = d.getDate();
      var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
      var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

      var theDate = curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year;

      var nameFile = items[0].getResponse() + ' - ' + items[14].getResponse() + ' - ' + theDate + '.pdf';

      //send an email with the PDF
      //If you don't want to send the PDF in the mail just delete everything
      //from here -------
      var email = 'YOUR@EMAIL.HERE, ANOTHER@EMAIL.HERE' ;
      var subject = 'SUBJECT HERE  ' +  theDate;
      var body = 'Hello, <br/>Please see attached PDF file.';
      var picture1 = DriveApp.getFileById(items[10].getResponse());
      var picture2 = DriveApp.getFileById(items[11].getResponse());
      var picture3 = DriveApp.getFileById(items[12].getResponse());
      var inlineImages = {};
        inlineImages[picture1.getId()] = picture1.getBlob();
        inlineImages[picture2.getId()] = picture2.getBlob();
        inlineImages[picture3.getId()] = picture3.getBlob();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: theDate + '<br/> <br/>' + 'Hello, <br/> <br/> This is an automated email from <br/> <br/>Please see attached door migration PDF for door' + "  " + items[14].getResponse() + "  " + '<br/> <br/> <b/r>' + 'Please see pictures of door below <br> <br> <br>' + 'Picture of ###:<br><img src="cid:' + picture1.getId() + '" /><br>' +
     'Picture of ###:<br><img src="cid:' + picture2.getId() + '" />' + 'Picture of ###:<br><img src="cid:' + picture3.getId() + '" />',
        inlineImages: inlineImages, 
        attachments:[
        //picture.getBlob(),
        {
        fileName: nameFile,
        content: theBlob.getBytes(),
        mimeType: "application/pdf"
        
      }]
        });
      
        //to here ------

        // save the PDF file in your Drive
  
        var savePDF = DriveApp.createFile (theBlob);

        //if you want to save the file in a specific folder use this code
        //get the ID from the folder link
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID HERE');
        var savePDF = folder.createFile (theBlob);

        savePDF.setName(nameFile);
  
        //delete the temp file
        DriveApp.getFileById(newTempFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);
     
  }
```