# How to place QR code that generated by formula as image in google doc (Export to PDF)?

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation, qr-code, google-sheets-api

I've generated QRcode by using image function (=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/....) and want to place in google doc, after the export to PDF, but it's show nothing, How do i place QRcode from spreadsheet in doc as image. Thank everyone for advance.

Here is code. (Just Example)

```
function createBulkPDFs(e) {

  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxx");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxx");
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("xxx");
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx").getSheetByName("eee");

  const range = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 6).getValues();
  var data = range[range.length - 1];
  createPDF(data[1],data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6], data[3] + "" + data[4], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder);
}

function createPDF(qcode, First, Last, address, quantity, pdfName, docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder) {

  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{qr}", qcode);
  body.replaceText("{fn}", First);
  body.replaceText("{ln}", Last);
  body.replaceText("{addr}", address);
  body.replaceText("{qty}", quantity);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();

  const pdfContentBolb = tempFile.getAs("application/pdf");
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBolb).setName(pdfName);
  tempFile.setTrashed(true);

  return pdfFile;}
```

Just want to place B column as image and save to PDF.
and google sheet here !!
[Click...](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xBIdN7GqAkBL7ri9noYa-BFkTOOSc1sWYdkesrK_2gc/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy the values from Google Spreadsheet to Google Document using Google Apps Script.
- The Google Spreadsheet is as follows.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your sample Spreadsheet and your script, it seems that you send the arguments to the function `createPDF` like `createPDF(data[1],data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6], data[3] + "" + data[4], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder)`.

  - The Spreadsheet has the values from the columns "A" to "F". But in your arguments, `data[6]` is used. In this case, an error occurs at `body.replaceText("{qty}", quantity)`.
  - From `createPDF(qcode, First, Last, address, quantity, pdfName, docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder)`, I thought that it is required to be `createPDF(data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[2] + "" + data[3], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder)`.
  - **If your actual Spreadsheet is different from your sample Spreadsheet, the following modified script doesn't work. So, please be careful this. In this answer, I modified your script using your sample Spreadsheet.**
- In order to retrieve the image from the cell of `=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/....`, I would like to propose to retrieve the image blob using UrlFetchApp. About the script for replacing the text to image, I used my sample script at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51913863).

  - The URL is retrieved from the formula and `data` you retrieved.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set each values of `xxx`.

```
function createBuikPDFs(e) {
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxx");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxx");
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("xxx");
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx").getSheetByName("eee");

  const values = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 6).getValues();
  const length = values.length;
  var data = values[length - 1];
  const formula = ws.getRange(length + 1, 2).getFormula();
  const url = formula.replace(/\=image\("/i, "").replace(/chl\="&.+/i, `chl=${data[5]}`);
  data[1] = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  createPDF(data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[2] + "" + data[3], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder);
}

function createPDF(qcode, First, Last, address, quantity, pdfName, docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder) {

  // This function is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51913863
  var replaceTextToImage = function (body, searchText, image, width) {
    var next = body.findText(searchText);
    if (!next) return;
    var r = next.getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, image);
    if (width && typeof width == "number") {
      var w = img.getWidth();
      var h = img.getHeight();
      img.setWidth(width);
      img.setHeight(width * h / w);
    }
    return next;
  };

  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();

  replaceTextToImage(body, "{qr}", qcode);
  body.replaceText("{fn}", First);
  body.replaceText("{ln}", Last);
  body.replaceText("{addr}", address);
  body.replaceText("{qty}", quantity);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();

  const pdfContentBolb = tempFile.getAs("application/pdf");
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBolb).setName(pdfName);
  tempFile.setTrashed(true);

  return pdfFile;
}
```

#### Note:

- **In this modified script, your sample Spreadsheet is used. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)
- Related thread

  - [Embed image uploaded by form to google doc using GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51912364)