# Auto Transfer Google sheet generated QR code to Google Doc as Image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a google sheet which automatically transfer data from google sheet to google doc. Now I generated a QR code in google sheet, but when I Transfer it as other data values from google sheet to google doc it says Cellimage in google doc. I want an actual generated QR code on Google doc. I am using app script to transfer the data as per mr Jeffery’s video on youtube. Any help will be appreciated.

QR code getting generated using column A and Column B

```
function onOpen() {

    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    const menu = ui.createMenu('GR Filled Form');
    menu.addItem('Create New Docs',   'createNewGoogleDocs')
    menu.addToUi();
}

    


function createNewGoogleDocs() {

      const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('Template ID');
 //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored




     const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderID')
 //Here we store the sheet as a variable




    const Sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = Sheet1.getActiveSheet();

    var only  = ['Gen4A','Gen4B','Gen4C','Gen4D','Gen4E','Gen5']
    if (only.indexOf(sheet.getName()) == -1)
    return;





 //Now we get all of the values as a 2D  



     const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();




//Start processing each spreadsheet row




     rows.forEach(function(row, index){


     if (index === 0) return;

     if (row[9]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder



        const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} GR FORM` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp



    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    //In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();
    //const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID");
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row



    body.replaceText('{{Pallet}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Batch}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Qty}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{QR Code Image}}', row[4]);
    
    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //const blobPDF = doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    //const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(row[0]+"-"+friendlyDate);
       
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    //const url = pdfFile.getUrl();
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 10).setValue(url)
    
  })
  
}
```

[image: sample Google sheet image.]

[image: output Image of QR Code in Google doc]

[sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-4O0csT9kOoQOnFfVMLNd45OSMpsDHrsmgRY1cslbyo/edit)

Comment: In order to correctly understand `Now I generated a QR code in google sheet`, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including it?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for responding. I Have updated post with sample spreadsheet image in case that works for you as I am accessing from cell phone right now unable to upload spreadsheet. Apologies for inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your showing image, I cannot understand how the QR code is put to the cells. Because when the QR code is put to the cells using a formula, the image can be retrieved from the URL of the formula. But when the QR code is directly put to the cells as the image, it is required to retrieve the image. So I asked to provide the sample Spreadsheet. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike please give me sometime I will upload the sample spreadsheet after sometime with app script code. Appreciate your reply. QR code is generated using Image formula.

Comment: @Tanaike sample spreadsheet updated. I have a google doc template with headers in spreadsheet. I hope this will work .

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation from your question. Can you provide your current script? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: @Tanaike code updated

Comment: @Tanaike if you require more information please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding your script. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that your sample Spreadsheet is different from your showing image and your script. So I'm confused about your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I want to transfer the google sheet data on google doc template automatically. This script transfer everything except QR Code. Google doc template has fields Batch, Qty, Pallet and QR Code which  is first row of google sheet. Only difference image and sample spreadsheet has is sample spreadsheet missing date column. That you can add.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I understand your flow and I think that the QR code can be retrieved from the Spreadsheet. But your sample Spreadsheet is different from your showing image and your script. So I'm worried that even when I modified your provided script, the script might not be able to be used. I apologize that your sample Spreadsheet is different from your showing image.

Comment: I updated sample spreadsheet. Now it’s matching as image. You can just provide me sample code how can I get QR code on Google Doc

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Worked absolutely perfect@Tanaike. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Tanaike one last quick question, when I scan QR in google sheet it shows values as expected but when I scan QR on Google doc is shows value ‘Nan’, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `one last quick question, when I scan QR in google sheet it shows values as expected but when I scan QR on Google doc is shows value ‘Nan’, do you have any idea about it?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your all questions soon. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: The QR code that generated using script , when I scan it the value for that QR code is showing ‘Nan’, but if I generate QR code on google sheet with formula the value is showing as expected. Is there something missing in script QR generating url formula?@Tanaike

Comment: @Tanaike I got it. Updated url little bit and it worked. Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your showing image of the Spreadsheet, I confirmed that column "E" has the image of the QR code. But, from your provided sample Spreadsheet, also I confirmed that column "E" has the formula like `=IMAGE("https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=160x160&data="&ENCODEURL(A2&" - "&B2),3)`. In this case, I thought that the QR code can be retrieved by retrieving the URL. In this answer, the QR code is retrieved from the URL and put into Google Document.

When your provided sample script is used, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set `'Template ID'` and `'FolderID'`.

```js
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51913863/7108653
  var replaceTextToImage = function (body, searchText, url, width = 200) {
    var next = body.findText(searchText);
    if (!next) return;
    var r = next.getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob());
    if (width && typeof width == "number") {
      var w = img.getWidth();
      var h = img.getHeight();
      img.setWidth(width);
      img.setHeight(width * h / w);
    }
    return next;
  };

  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('Template ID');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderID');
  const Sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = Sheet1.getActiveSheet();
  var only = ['Gen4A', 'Gen4B', 'Gen4C', 'Gen4D', 'Gen4E', 'Gen5']
  if (only.indexOf(sheet.getName()) == -1) return;
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[9]) return;
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} GR FORM`, destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();
    body.replaceText('{{Pallet}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Batch}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Qty}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Date}}', friendlyDate);
    replaceTextToImage(body, '{{QR Code Image}}', "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=160x160&data=" + encodeURIComponent(row[0] - row[1]));
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 10).setValue(url)
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script can be used for your sample Spreadsheet. So, when you changed the structure of the Spreadsheet and your actual situation is different from your sample Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. So please be careful about this.

#### References:

- Related threads

  - [Embed image uploaded by form to google doc using GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51912364/7108653)
  - [Replacing Text to Image for Google Document using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f84831455dea5c394e48caaee0058b26)