Is it possible get Image from Google Sheets to Google Docs Template when creating
This is my google sheet image.

I want when script creating from template import to here is it possible?

The code on here I am using for creating the google docs
// extract values from array of data
      var date_time = data[i][0];
      convert_time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_time), "GMT+8", "E | dd/MMM/yyyy | hh:mm:ss a");
      var emp_name = data[i][1];
      var emp_id = data[i][2];
      var emp_dept = data[i][3];
      var emp_laptop = data[i][4];
      var emp_serialno = data[i][5];
      var emp_acc1 = data[i][6];
      var emp_acc2 = data[i][7];
      var emp_acc3 = data[i][8];
      var emp_acc4 = data[i][9];
      var emp_acc5 = data[i][10];
      var emp_sign = data[i][11];
      var it_sign = data[i][12];
      
// only proceed if got Body of new File
      if (openNewFile) {
        
        // replace tags with data from sheet
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<date-time>>', convert_time);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-name>>', emp_name);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-id>>', emp_id);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-dept>>', emp_dept);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-laptop>>', emp_laptop);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-serialnumber>>', emp_serialno);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-acc1>>', emp_acc1);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-acc2>>', emp_acc2);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-acc3>>', emp_acc3);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-acc4>>', emp_acc4);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-acc5>>', emp_acc5);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-sign>>', emp_sign);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<it-sign>>', it_sign);


Most probably yes. You need to get the url from  the cell, then fetch the image from Google drive as blob and then get the correct position of the <<it_sign>> and insert the blob image you got...

I thought that this answer might be useful for understanding for resolving your issue. Auto Transfer Google sheet generated QR code to Google Doc as Image When the script of this answer is reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?
Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual script. So, this is a simple modification. Please reflect this in your actual script.
Modified script:
Please add the following function to your script.
// ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71151203/7108653
var replaceTextToImage = function (body, searchText, url, width = 200) {
  var next = body.findText(searchText);
  if (!next) return;
  var r = next.getElement();
  r.asText().setText("");
  var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob());
  if (width && typeof width == "number") {
    var w = img.getWidth();
    var h = img.getHeight();
    img.setWidth(width);
    img.setHeight(width * h / w);
  }
  return next;
};

And, please modify your script as follows.
From:
newFileBody.replaceText('<<emp-sign>>', emp_sign);
newFileBody.replaceText('<<it-sign>>', it_sign);

To:
replaceTextToImage(newFileBody, '<<emp-sign>>', emp_sign);
replaceTextToImage(newFileBody, '<<it-sign>>', it_sign);

Note:

From your showing images, I guessed that in your situation, var emp_sign = data[i][11] and var it_sign = data[i][12] are the image URLs. Also, it supposes that the files of your URLs are publicly shared, and your URLs can be directly accessed to the images. Please be careful about this.
If you want to change the image size, please add the image width to the 4th argument of the function replaceTextToImage.
If you use my modification to your script and the script doesn't work, please provide your whole script. I would like to confirm it.


Yeah, it works the way I wanted it to. Thanks!

@Ah Chuan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
