# How can I automate the adding of an image to a Google Doc from a url to a Drive file located in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have created a script to Auto Fill a Google Doc from a Google Form Submission (via Google Sheets) but I am struggling to auto fill an image into the Google Doc from a Drive url created in the Google Sheet (via an IF formula).

Essentially the Google doc is designed to simplify some admin work. The person submitting the Form chooses who the document is being written by and the digital signature of that person should be auto populated.

Here is what I have tried. Everything works well except the replaceTextToImage function - I am lost! Thanks in advance for your help.

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  // @ts-ignore
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var COMPANYNAME = e.values[2];
  var CONTACTNAME = e.values[7];
  var DATE = e.values[9];
  var STREET = e.values[3];
  var TOWN = e.values[4];
  var POSTCODE = e.values[5];
  var COUNTRY = e.values[6];
  var PURPOSE = e.values[10];
  var JOBTITLE = e.values[8];
  var DIRECTOR = e.values[11];
  var ADDRESS_2 = e.values[12];
  
  //file  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1Dd78JKEHDr6JY3b3N9zxNHu6_7tK3-NSJPIdNVp_SNQ'); 
  
  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1zyodJvnwabTRM7horzM0HRBw04b0IxbI')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(COMPANYNAME + ',' + DATE, folder); 
  
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{COMPANYNAME}}', COMPANYNAME); 
  body.replaceText('{{CONTACTNAME}}', CONTACTNAME);  
  body.replaceText('{{DATE}}', DATE); 
  body.replaceText('{{STREET}}', STREET); 
  body.replaceText('{{ADDRESS_2}}', ADDRESS_2); 
  body.replaceText('{{TOWN}}', TOWN); 
  body.replaceText('{{POSTCODE}}', POSTCODE); 
  body.replaceText('{{COUNTRY}}', COUNTRY); 
  body.replaceText('{{PURPOSE}}', PURPOSE); 
  body.replaceText('{{JOBTITLE}}', JOBTITLE); 
  body.replaceText('{{DIRECTOR}}', DIRECTOR); 

 //function embedding image to document with a specified size
    var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, fileId) {
    var width = 600; // Please set this.
    var blob = DriveApp.getFileById('1Dd78JKEHDr6JY3b3N9zxNHu6_7tK3-NSJPIdNVp_SNQ').getBlob();
    var r = body.findText(searchText).getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, blob);
    var w = img.getWidth();
    var h = img.getHeight();
    img.setWidth(width);
    img.setHeight(width * h / w);
    }

// Get the image fileID
  var image = e.values[13]; // xx being the row number in which the link to the uploaded image is
  var imageID = String(image).split("=")[1]; //gives you the fileID of the uploaded image

// Use the function replaceTextToImage
  replaceTextToImage(body,'{{imageID}}', imageID); // replaces the {{image}} tag with the uploaded image
  
  //Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

Comment: About `Here is what I have tried. Everything works well except the replaceTextToImage function`, if your `replaceTextToImage` is [my sample script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51913863/7108653), I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. And also, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your current issue, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 0):

So I think the problematic line in the code is this one:

```
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById('1Dd78JKEHDr6JY3b3N9zxNHu6_7tK3-NSJPIdNVp_SNQ').getBlob();
```

Please replace it with the following:

```
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
```

What was happening is that since `fileId` is actually a defined parameter of the function `replaceImageToText`, removing it from inside the function and replacing it with an actual ID of a file resulted in the file with ID `1Dd78JKEHDr6JY3b3N9zxNHu6_7tK3-NSJPIdNVp_SNQ` being considered as the image every single time the function was called instead of the image that was uploaded through your form.

I tried this out myself and it worked with a random image I uploaded to my drive. Please try this fix and see if it works for you too. Hope this helps!