# Convert Binary Image to Image and Insert into Google Doc - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api, binary-image

We have a license for https://www.qr-code-generator.com/ which has an API located here https://www.qr-code-generator.com/qr-code-api/

I'm using Google Apps Script in a Google Doc.

When I make an API call I get Raw Binary Images as a response.

```
function APICall() {
  var url = "https://api.qr-code-generator.com/v1/create?access-token=dAlKmUnRsrPIFBLY_ix5YU0LRuMsNgM9MnFTmVHJwD4JRAeBmdzrPmmUAqi9zNyX";
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload":{
    "frame_name": "no-frame",
    "qr_code_text": "https://www.qr-code-generator.com/",
    "image_format": "PNG",
    "qr_code_logo": "scan-me-square",
    "download":1
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  //return "Testing";
  return response;
}
```

I get the following responses

SVG https://pastebin.com/nF2YHzux

JPG https://pastebin.com/8HCYdeEu

PNG https://pastebin.com/J68U2PMy

This is where I start running into problems.

I can't find a good way to push the actual image of the QR code to my Google Doc.

This is the closest thing I've found but I don't think I can embed an SVG into a Google Doc.

https://dev.to/benjaminblack/using-a-string-of-svg-as-an-image-source-8mo

```
  let svg = APICall();
  let blob = new Blob([svg], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = url;
  image.addEventListener('load', () => URL.revokeObjectURL(url), {once: true});
```

but I get "ReferenceError: Blob is not defined". I'm not sure if this is even possible.

EDIT Include the actual function that is calling APICall():

```
//This function currently has 2 purposes. I replace any instance of <<QR>> code as the text string that is returned from APICall()
function QRify(){

  var activeDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var id = activeDoc.getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id); //Get the ID of the copy
  
  var head = doc.getHeader();
  var body = doc.getBody(); //Get the body of the copy
  var foot = doc.getFooter();

  var replaceText = "<<QR>>";
  var code = APICall();

  //var img = new Image();
  //img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + hexToBase64(code);

  //head.appendChild(img);
  
  let svg = APICall();
  let blob = new Blob([svg], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = url;
  image.addEventListener('load', () => URL.revokeObjectURL(url), {once: true});
   
  
  Replace Strings with Form variables
    if(head != null){
      head.replaceText(replaceText, code);
    }

   if(body != null){
     body.replaceText(replaceText, code);
   }

   if(foot != null){
     foot.replaceText(replaceText, code);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between the top script and the bottom script. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, about `I get the following responses`, when your request is run, 3 data are returned. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, about `This is the closest thing I've found but I don't think I can embed an SVG into a Google Doc.`, in this case, how about putting PNG data into Google Document? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike No worries your English was perfectly understandable. I will update the question

Comment: @Tanaike Hopefully this makes it more clear. I was originally replacing any instance of <<QR>> in the document with the string that I get back from APICall() but as that is a binary image it doesn't do much good. 

The SVG blob section of the code is my attempt to convert the binary image data to a Blob, send that blob to a URL and then embed that image by URL to the google doc.

Comment: Thank you for replying. What is `QRify()`? That includes both Google Apps Script and Javascript. So, I cannot understand it. I apologize for this. And, it seems that `APICall()` returns no values. How about this? And, about `I get the following responses`, when your request is run, 3 data are returned. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, about `This is the closest thing I've found but I don't think I can embed an SVG into a Google Doc.`, in this case, how about putting PNG data into Google Document? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: My fault! I had omitted part of the APICall() function. I am making a HTTP POST request from api.qr-code-generator.com and the response from the POST is a string of Binary Image Data which I can get in different formats by changing  ```"image_format": "PNG",``` ```"image_format": "JPG",``` or ```"image_format": "SVG",``` I only get 1 response at a time, I just wanted to show the different formats the response was available in, sorry if this caused confusion.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your script. From your reply, I proposed a simple sample script for using the data of `var code = APICall();`. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your showing script, I thought that in this case, the blob can be retrieved from `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);`. When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, `<<QR>>` in the document body is replaced with the retrieved image blob. So, please put `<<QR>>` to the document body. And, in this case, as a sample, the active Document is used.

```js
function sample() {
  // Ref: https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/08/20/replacing-text-to-image-for-google-document-using-google-apps-script/ Author: me
  // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51912364
  var replaceTextToImage = function (body, searchText, image, width) {
    var next = body.findText(searchText);
    if (!next) return;
    var r = next.getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, image);
    if (width && typeof width == "number") {
      var w = img.getWidth();
      var h = img.getHeight();
      img.setWidth(width);
      img.setHeight(width * h / w);
    }
    return next;
  };

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var replaceText = "<<QR>>";
  var code = APICall();
  var blob = code.getBlob();
  do {
    var next = replaceTextToImage(body, replaceText, blob, 200);
  } while (next);
}
```

- When this script is run, the image blob is retrieved from `var code = APICall();`, and `<<QR>>` is replaced with the image.
- `200` of `replaceTextToImage(body, replaceText, blob, 200)` is the image width. Please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Class HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response)