Replacing google doc template text with placeholder {{text}} by google sheet images (charts: line, bar,pie)
I make a daily log report of my work in Google Sheets, and have to submit that report on a monthly basis. For that, I have a template report in my Google Drive account. That template needs to be updated with text and charts from Google Sheet with placeholders {{}}. My code replaces the text placeholders with appropriate text, but the image placeholders (Graphs: line/pie/bar) are not replaced with images.
Please help.
Here is my code:
function docTemplate(){
    timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
    const now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),timeZone,"MMMM-YYYY")

    const googledocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1DXzyPGhjOVKMmb09J7ZCKI-ij7c-QecaPI-jFqe3gEQ');
    const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('17tWJSKjOdEAMGmTf1l8dKZg52uGpQdNe');
    const sheetURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
    const dataSheet = getSheetByID('552896708');
    const rows = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(arr => arr.some(v => !!v));
    const chartSheet = getSheetByID('339388881');
    const copy = googledocTemplate.makeCopy('Monthly Report:' + now, destinationFolder); 
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();

    body.replaceText('{{Date}}',now);
    body.replaceText('{{Link}}', sheetURL);

    var content = body.getText();
    var placeholderPattern = /{{(.*?)}}/g;
    var placeholder = content.match(placeholderPattern);

    placeholder.forEach(function(placeholder){
        var searchText = placeholder.substring(2, placeholder.length-2).trim();

        var charts = chartSheet.getCharts()[searchText];
        if(charts){
            body.replaceText(placeholder, ' ');
            body.appendImage(charts);
        }
    })

    doc.saveAndClose();
}

But I couldn't replace the placeholders {{Figure 1}} and {{Figure 2}} with images in my template document. Please see the following image to understand what I mean.


Does this help?

Modification points:

In your script, I think that var searchText = placeholder.substring(2, placeholder.length-2).trim(); is the string value. But, chartSheet.getCharts() is an array. So, chartSheet.getCharts()[searchText]; is always false. Also, in order to put a chart, it is required to use a blob.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
Before you use this script, please modify obj to your actual situation. In this modification, in order to identify each chart, I used an object including the chart titles and the placeholders. So, please modify it to your actual situation.
function docTemplate() {
  timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  const now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "MMMM-YYYY")

  const googledocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1DXzyPGhjOVKMmb09J7ZCKI-ij7c-QecaPI-jFqe3gEQ');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('17tWJSKjOdEAMGmTf1l8dKZg52uGpQdNe');
  const sheetURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  const dataSheet = getSheetByID('552896708');
  const rows = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(arr => arr.some(v => !!v));
  const chartSheet = getSheetByID('339388881');
  const copy = googledocTemplate.makeCopy('Monthly Report:' + now, destinationFolder);
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  const body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText('{{Date}}', now);
  body.replaceText('{{Link}}', sheetURL);

  var content = body.getText();
  var placeholderPattern = /{{(.*?)}}/g;
  var placeholder = content.match(placeholderPattern);


  // --- I modified the below script.
  // Ref: https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/08/20/replacing-text-to-image-for-google-document-using-google-apps-script/ Author: me
  // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51912364
  var replaceTextToImage = function (body, searchText, image, width) {
    var next = body.findText(searchText);
    if (!next) return;
    var r = next.getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, image);
    if (width && typeof width == "number") {
      var w = img.getWidth();
      var h = img.getHeight();
      img.setWidth(width);
      img.setHeight(width * h / w);
    }
    return next;
  };
  var obj = [
    { chartTitle: "sample1", placeholder: "{{Figure 1}}" },
    { chartTitle: "sample2", placeholder: "{{Figure 2}}" },
  ];
  chartSheet.getCharts().forEach(c => {
    var title = c.getOptions().get("title");
    var p = obj.find(({ chartTitle }) => chartTitle == title);
    if (p) {
      replaceTextToImage(body, p.placeholder, c.getBlob());
    }
  });
  // ---


  doc.saveAndClose();
}


If you want to adjust the chart size, for example, please modify replaceTextToImage(body, p.placeholder, c.getBlob()); to `replaceTextToImage(body, p.placeholder, c.getBlob(), 200);.
When this script is run with the value obj and Spreadsheet and Document, I confirmed that the placeholders of {{Figure 1}} and {{Figure 2}} are correctly replaced with the required charts.

Note:

Unfortunately, I cannot know your Spreadsheet. So, when this modification cannot be used, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for using the template Document? By this, I would like to confirm it.


Thanks for your valuable modification and Yes, it works now. But each time the placeholder {{Figure 1}}, {{Figure 1}} .... replaced by same image/chart from my excel sheet, also the size/dimension of the images did not fit the window.

@Kisna Thank you for replying. From Thanks for your valuable modification and Yes, it works now., I understood that your issue the image placeholders (Graphs: line/pie/bar) are not replaced with images was resolved. About your new issue each time the placeholder {{Figure 1}}, {{Figure 1}} .... replaced by same image/chart from my excel sheet, also the size/dimension of the images did not fit the window., I would like to support you. But, this is a new issue. So, can you post it as a new question? If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?
