Google forms to Pdf add image
I transfer the information I entered via Google form to pdf via Google Document. Texts are added, but I don't know how to add images. Document file id etc. are all present in the codes. After submitting the form, the image to be added will be doc id =
1I63WRYGP169inM1TvCJIaMSTBozaNZygGrdvPLcTLrechAzrVZWmjWKVuMTKM92vZDV7p1JU
, but I could not find how to do it.
  var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById('1cc1xjtE6WyYjVVwY95earN6xht2mP01EEPhAyC-yFHE');
  var TempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1vaXCrOJAg1x2JCzEng9nSPn6om8dWmib');
  var PDFFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('16r-564UEEuBcyfTIX0xnjJRk6bFJjzL1');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kZFrbnjgVnq7wB4mFYAMCjFiDB2PAfkmbYGvhLg_U00');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Form Yanıtları 1');
var data = sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),1,1,9).getValues()
      data.forEach(r=>{
        var item1 = r[1]
        var item2 = r[2]
        var item3 = r[3]
        var item4 = r[4]
        var item5 = r[5]
        var item6 = r[6]
        var item7 = r[7]
        var item8 = r[8]
        var item9 = r[9]

           item6 = LanguageApp.translate(Utilities.formatDate(item6,'GMT+7','dd MMMM yyyy'),'en','tr').split(' ').map((a,i) =>{if(i != 2 || parseInt(a)>2100){return a}; a = parseInt(a); return a}).join(' ')

item7 = Utilities.formatDate(item7, 'GMT+3', 'HH:mm'); // Denetim başlama saati
item8 = Utilities.formatDate(item8, 'GMT+3', 'HH:mm'); // Denetim bitiş saati


CreatePDF(docFile,TempFolder,PDFFolder,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9)

      })
}

function CreatePDF(docFile,TempFolder,PDFFolder,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9){
var tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(TempFolder)
var tempDoc = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId())
    tempDoc.getBody().replaceText("{MAĞAZA ADI}",item2)
    tempDoc.getBody().replaceText("{DENETİMİ YAPAN}",item3)
    tempDoc.getBody().replaceText("{İLGİLİ HAFTA}",item4)
    tempDoc.getBody().replaceText("{MAĞAZA PUANI}",item5)
    tempDoc.getBody().replaceText("{DENETİM TARİHİ}",item6)
    tempDoc.getBody().replaceText("{DENETİM BAŞLAMA SAATİ}",item7)
    tempDoc.getBody().replaceText("{DENETİM BİTİŞ SAATİ}",item8)
    tempDoc.getBody().replaceText("{BİR ÖNCEKİ DENETİMİ YAPAN}",item9)
    tempDoc.saveAndClose()
   TempFolder.removeFile(tempFile)

var PdfContent = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF)
var PdfFile = PDFFolder.createFile(PdfContent).setName(item2)

MailApp.sendEmail(item1, item2 + ' ŞUBE', 'DENETİM FORMU..', {
  attachments: [PdfFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
});
} ```


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script, your Spreeadsheet, and images you want to use. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

sheet = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kZFrbnjgVnq7wB4mFYAMCjFiDB2PAfkmbYGvhLg_U00/edit#gid=472023705
form = https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PmyPetO808DZfWjouX--9heAcSSlLdnY38FCZ50DUWI/edit
theme doc = https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cc1xjtE6WyYjVVwY95earN6xht2mP01EEPhAyC-yFHE/edit
I send data to the document theme via the form. The code I wrote converts the document into pdf and only translates the texts. I want to add an image to the document and have it appear in the pdf file.

Thank you for replying. Can you provide more information about I want to add an image to the document? Which do you want to use the placeholder for the image in your showing script?

Each of the items is attached as text because there are 9 items that are sent as text in the form and written to pdf. When I add the item10, it is added as a (google drive image) link. I want to add it to the document as {IMAGE1}. Let the link to item10 appear in the pdf as {IMAGE1}.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you wanted to replace a placeholder {IMAGE1} with the image of column "K". If my understanding is correct, where can I see the placeholder {IMAGE1} in your provided Google Document?

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cc1xjtE6WyYjVVwY95earN6xht2mP01EEPhAyC-yFHE/edit     available here on the second page

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize. By the way, before you test my script, please confirm the sheet name and the placeholders, again. Because when I copied your script, there were some garbled texts. I'm worried whether the garbled text does not lead to another issue.

From your provided sample Spreadsheet, Document, and your script, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
Before you use this script, please set your Spreadsheet ID, Document ID, and folder IDs. And, please confirm the sheet name and the placeholders, again. Because when I copied your script, there were some garbled texts.
function myFunction() {
  var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById('###');
  var TempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('###');
  var PDFFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('###');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###');

  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Form Yanıtları 1');
  var data = sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 11).getValues()
  data.forEach(r => {
    var item1 = r[1]//BİRİNCİ SÜTUN
    var item2 = r[2]//İKİNCİ SÜTUN
    var item3 = r[3]//ÜÇÜNCÜ SÜTN
    var item4 = r[4]//DÖRDÜNCÜ
    var item5 = r[5]//BEŞİNCİ
    var item6 = r[6]//ALTINCI
    var item7 = r[7]//YEDİNCİ
    var item8 = r[8]//SEKİZİNCİ
    var item9 = r[9]//DOKUZUNCU
    item6 = LanguageApp.translate(Utilities.formatDate(item6, 'GMT+7', 'dd MMMM yyyy'), 'en', 'tr').split(' ').map((a, i) => { if (i != 2 || parseInt(a) > 2100) { return a }; a = parseInt(a); return a }).join(' ')
    item7 = Utilities.formatDate(item7, 'GMT+3', 'HH:mm'); // Denetim başlama saati
    item8 = Utilities.formatDate(item8, 'GMT+3', 'HH:mm'); // Denetim bitiş saati
    CreatePDF(docFile, TempFolder, PDFFolder, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, r[10].split("=")[1]);
  })
}

function CreatePDF(docFile, TempFolder, PDFFolder, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, id) {
  var tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(TempFolder);
  var tempDoc = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  var body = tempDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{MAĞAZA ADI}", item2);
  body.replaceText("{DENETİMİ YAPAN}", item3);
  body.replaceText("{İLGİLİ HAFTA}", item4);
  body.replaceText("{MAĞAZA PUANI}", item5);
  body.replaceText("{DENETİM TARİHİ}", item6);
  body.replaceText("{DENETİM BAŞLAMA SAATİ}", item7);
  body.replaceText("{DENETİM BİTİŞ SAATİ}", item8);
  body.replaceText("{BİR ÖNCEKİ DENETİMİ YAPAN}", item9);

  // Ref: https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/08/20/replacing-text-to-image-for-google-document-using-google-apps-script/ Author: me
  // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51912364
  var replaceTextToImage = function (body, searchText, image, width) {
    var next = body.findText(searchText);
    if (!next) return;
    var r = next.getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, image);
    if (width && typeof width == "number") {
      var w = img.getWidth();
      var h = img.getHeight();
      img.setWidth(width);
      img.setHeight(width * h / w);
    }
    return next;
  };
  replaceTextToImage(body, "{IMAGE1}", DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob(), 500);
  tempDoc.saveAndClose();
  TempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
  var PdfContent = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var PdfFile = PDFFolder.createFile(PdfContent).setName(item2);
  MailApp.sendEmail(item1, item2 + ' ŞUBE', 'DENETİM FORMU..', { attachments: [PdfFile.getBlob()] });
}


When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the last row of the sheet. And, a PDF file is created using a template Document. And, an email is sent including the PDF file.

In this modification, you can adjust the size of the inserted image by 500 of replaceTextToImage(body, "{IMAGE1}", DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob(), 500);.


Note:

When I tested the above script using your provided Spreadsheet and Document, no error occurred. I confirmed an email including the correctly created PDF file. If you change Spreadsheet and Document, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.


Thank you for your attention, it worked completely. What should I do when I need to select IMAGE2 IMAGE3 IMAGE4

@Esat Kurtul Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of What should I do when I need to select IMAGE2 IMAGE3 IMAGE4, how about modifying {IMAGE1} of replaceTextToImage(body, "{IMAGE1}", DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob(), 500);? But, I'm not sure about your new question. If this was not your expected answer to your new question, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it.
